# $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows does not update correctly with column clear filter

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

How to get the rows that are actually in the "Showing Items"? 
$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows seems to be giving inconsistent values.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FRaCNxKhZ242rFyqNDkm?p=preview

```
gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        var allvisiblerows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
        $scope.visibleRowsCount = allvisiblerows.length;
    }, 0);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `filterChanged` is that it is raised as soon as the filters change but at that time the data has not necessarily been filtered. To fix this, rather than listening to the `filterChanged` you can listen to `rowsRendered` event and that will fix the issue.

```
gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered($scope, function () {
    var allvisiblerows = $scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
    $scope.visibleRowsCount = allvisiblerows.length;
});
```

This way you can also get rid of the `$timeout.`